# Calculate the percentage of zeros of the rows of a data frame

Tags: r

I need to calculate the percentage of zeros for each row in a data frame and discard the rows that have a percentage higher than a given threshold (60%). I figured I could add the values as a new variable with `mutate()` but I still don't know how to calculate them in the first place, since the number of columns is very large. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

We can write a little function to test for the sum of 0's and then `apply()` it to remove all desired rows using `Base R`:

```
## sampling data ##

set.seed(82)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10, replace = T), 
                 b = sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10, replace = T), 
                 c = sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10, replace = T),
                 d = sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10, replace = T), 
                 e = sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10, replace = T))

## function to find rows ##

row.discard <- function(vec, tresh = 0.1){
  t <- sum(vec == 0) / length(vec)
    if(t > tresh){
    T
    }
    else{
    F
    }
}

## apply to our df ##

ind <- apply(df, 1, row.discard)

## result ##

df[!ind,]

  a b c d e
1 3 2 2 3 2
5 2 1 1 2 1
6 1 2 3 3 3
7 1 3 3 1 2
```

Note: Since we are using `apply()` to get the index, thus not applying it to the df itself we will not be bothered by the conversion to matrix that is inherent with the usage of the `apply()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` function, you can pass a function per row and request the sum of 0 then divide by the total and multiply by 100 and you have your percentage.

With the following reproducible example:

```r
df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(Row1 = sample(c(1,0),20,replace = TRUE),
                              Row2 = sample(c(1,0),20,replace = TRUE))))

     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
Row1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
Row2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0
```

You can obtain the count of 0 and their expression as percentage by doing:

```r
# Count of 0
apply(df,1, function(x) sum(x == 0))

Row1 Row2 
   8   11

# Count of 0 expressed as percentage
apply(df,1, function(x) sum(x == 0)/ncol(df)*100)

Row1 Row2 
  40   55
```

Finally, if you want to extract rows with a certain percentage of 0 (let's say above 41%), we can do:

```r
test <- apply(df,1, function(x) sum(x == 0)/ncol(df)*100)

df[test > 41,]
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20
Row2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0
```

Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
percent0 <- apply(myDF, 1, function (x) { sum(x==0) / length(x) })
myDF <- myDF[percent0 < 0.6,]
```